# Eye of Gnome zoom 100% gone in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: gnome, 15.10, eog

The other day I finally upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10. I've opened up an image today using Image Viewer (**eog version 3.16.3**) and found that the button to scale 1:1 or 100% (don't remember what it was exactly) has gone.

I've tried:

- View menu - I checked the [help](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/zoom.html.en), apparently there should be "View > Normal size" but I could not find it. The options I have are:

  - Statusbar
  - Image Gallery
  - Side Panel
  - Zoom In
  - Zoom Out
  - Best Fit
  - Fullscreen
  - Slide Show
- Editing the toolbar - again, I looked at the [help](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/toolbar.html.en) which suggests I should be able to edit the toolbar, but I can find no such options
- Preferences, looking for any option to enable more buttons / zoom options
- I can zoom in/out using the slider. So I can either:

  - Manually drag to 100% - very fiddly!
  - Zoom in to 300% then right click on the slider two times (-100% each time) - really clunky
- I've enabled Image Gallery to look for options (nothing obvious)
- I've enabled Side Panel to look for options (again, nothing obvious)

Has the option been removed? Or maybe something broke in the upgrade? Any suggestions to get this 100% zoom button back would be greatly appreciated - I used it a lot to view images... at 100% zoom :)

Comment: I would've loved to include an image here to show what I mean, but because I don't have enough reputation, I can't provide as much information as I'd like. Which seems very counter-intuitive. So apologies, I can't embed an image or provide more than 2 links, so here is [the image](http://s.asgrim.com/1e022a.png)

Comment: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/772164/37165) has several answers and hinted the button is missing forever in Ubuntu 16.04. I suppose the button is already missing from 15.10 release.

Answer (score 1):

You can still jump to 100% via the [keyboard shortcut](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/shortcuts.html.en) `Ctrl+0`

Comment: It does work, although I still need to manually stretch the window to show the full picture again (even if the picture was smaller than my monitor resolution anyway). It makes things less convenient when you open the smallest picture of a batch then navigate left/right to see all pictures, as the window will stay small (and the picture zoomed out). A trick I found was to identify the biggest picture in the batch and open it first, then navigate left/right, so you can compare everything at the same zoom (100% if the biggest picture is smaller than your monitor).