# Where is the 1:1 zoom button in Image Viewer in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, eog

I want to use the 1:1 zoom in Image Viewer (eog). But i can't find the icon (or the option), which used to be there in the 14.04 release. Where is it?

[image: Screenshot of Image Viewer with no menu bar icons]

Compare it with this image:

[image]

This has the "1" icon which lets me view the image at 100% zoom.

Also, other Ubuntu "stock" applications like Text Editor (gedit), Videos, etc do not have the toolbar buttons. Is this the new look going forward?

Comment: Are you using any third party repositories?

Comment: Post unrelated questions in separate posts, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu `16.04` is based on gnome `3.18`. Applications such as `eog` or `gedit` (are part of gnome desktop environment) are updated versions and this is modified interface. In `eog` you can click <kbd>+</kbd> and set 1:1 zoom (just move to mark).

If you don't like the way it looks you can downgrade applications to previous versions like [this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766055/how-do-i-downgrade-gedit-to-a-previous-3-10-4-version-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts).

Comment: ah Gnome didn't occur to me. i'm still used to their old classic desktop environment before Unity came along :-} I'd've accepted your answer, but clicking "+" doesn't show any 1:1 mark.

Comment: @garyf there is small vertical line under zoom slider which means 1:1 zoom

Comment: This is strange. It does show on my desktop monitor. I have eog 3.18.2 on my both my desktop and my laptop.I pressed 1 on my keyboard, and the slider is at the 1:1 zoom point.

But there is no mark when i use eog on my laptop. (Else i wouldn't have asked this question in the first place.) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzNsvDx_ae6baVdoSS1CX1Y0QzQ However, the slider does feel snappy at that area.

This might be nit-picking now; i'd consider my question resolved. Thanks!~ :-)

Comment: @garyf You can't see it because of light radiance theme, change for a while to ambiance and the mark will be in the right place :)

Answer (score 1):

Click the <kbd>↗</kbd> button to view the picture in full-screen mode. In that mode, there is an auto-hiding top toolbar with all the old toolbar icons.

If you use the **Actual size** mode often, you may find it useful to use the keyboard shortcut. Just press the <kbd>1</kbd> key on your keyboard and press <kbd>F</kbd> to return to **Best fit** mode.